# Jquery mouseenter and mouseleave is deprecated in Next.js, Tailwind

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, tailwind-css, jquery-hover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTy0K.png)

I wanted to create `useEffect` variables and put it to true/false when user hovers on parent `div`.
I want to use that hover variable in a child `div` with image and resize image when user hovers on parent `div` with `id="infoCard"`.

**Code-**

```js
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

<div
  className="flex flex-col md:flex-row font-inter py-7 px-2 border-b rounded-xl cursor-pointer hover:shadow-lg pr-6 transition duration-200 ease-out first:border-t hover:bg-red-100 mb-2"
  id="infoCard"
>
  <div className="relative h-40 w-64 md:h-52 md:w-80 flex-shrink-0 ml-6">
    <Image
      src={img}
      layout="fill"
      objectFit="cover"
      className={`rounded-2xl scale-95 ${hover ? "scale-100" : ""
        } transform transition duration-200 ease-out`}
    />
  </div>

  <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow pl-5 ml-2 mt-2 md:mt-0">
    <div className="flex justify-between">
      <p>
        {location} {city}
      </p>
      <HeartIcon className="h-7 cursor-pointer" />
    </div>

    <h4 className="text-xl">{title}</h4>

    <div className="border-b w-10 pt-2" />

    <p className="pt-2 text-sm text-gray-500 flex-grow">
      {numberOfGuest}
      {description}
    </p>

    <div className="flex justify-between items-end">
      <p className="flex items-center">
        <StarIcon className="h-5 text-red-400" />
        {star}
      </p>

      <div>
        <p className="text-lg pb-2 font-semibold lg:text-2xl">{price}</p>
        <p className="text-right font-light">{total}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the question here? You've given some indication of what you want to do but no problem statement regarding trying to do it and problems you are having

Comment: The problem is, mouseenter and mouseleave is showing to be deprecated, so it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without the hover state with just CSS. Take a look at the documentation on group-hover classes [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover). They work like this:

```
<div class="group">
   <img class="transform scale-95 group-hover:scale-100" />
</div>
```

[Here's](https://play.tailwindcss.com/gErBaqORVu) a minimal example of how you could do this. Note that you also need to extend the variants of the scale classes in the `tailwind.config.js` file as it's not included by default.

As a side note: You don't typically use jQuery in a React-based projects. If you need to detect hover, React has built-in mouse events. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events).